# How do I validate a user's IP address against a list of IP addresses in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

IP addresses are stored in my table in any of following ways.

```
192.12.34.12
192.12.#.12
192.#.34.12
```

Now in my applicaton I want to validate user IP address against this table automatically by capturing IP address of logged in user using the .net code.

Now if user IP is

```
192.12.34.12
192.12.45.12

192.56.34.12-- it should be valid.
191.12.34.12-- Invalid
```

How can I create a SQL query or a stored proc which will validate logged in user's IP address against this table?

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `LIKE` operator, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM IPRecords
WHERE @UsersIp like replace(IP, '#', '%')
```

However, this approach can be very problematic performance-wise if you have a lot of records in your table (it cannot use any index).

If performance is really a problem, an alternative approach could be to:

- split the IP across four numeric columns
- use `null` to indicate a wildcard (for example, your last rule would become `192, null, 34, 12`)
- on the client, split the IP in the corresponding 4 parts and use a condition such as:

  `WHERE (IP1=@IP1 OR IP1 is null) AND (IP2=@IP2 OR IP2 is null) AND ...`

This way I think you could use indexes on the four columns to speed things up if needed.

Answer (score 3):

You could use PARSENAME function to split the IP addresse values into four parts and compare them individually.

*Create and populate test data script*:

```
CREATE TABLE ipaddresses
( 
    ip VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ipaddresses (ip) VALUES
    ('192.12.34.12'),
    ('192.12.#.12'),
    ('192.#.34.12');
```

## Scenario #1

```
DECLARE @userip VARCHAR(20)
SET     @userip = '192.56.34.12'

;WITH ips AS
(
    SELECT  REPLACE(ip, '#', '%') AS ip
    FROM    ipaddresses
)
SELECT  COUNT(ip) AS validcount
FROM    ips
WHERE   PARSENAME(@userip, 1) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 1)
AND     PARSENAME(@userip, 2) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 2)
AND     PARSENAME(@userip, 3) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 3)
AND     PARSENAME(@userip, 4) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 4);

VALIDCOUNT
----------
    1
```

## Scenario #2

```
DECLARE @userip VARCHAR(20)
SET     @userip = '191.12.34.12'

;WITH ips AS
(
    SELECT  REPLACE(ip, '#', '%') AS ip
    FROM    ipaddresses
)
SELECT  COUNT(ip) AS validcount
FROM    ips
WHERE   PARSENAME(@userip, 1) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 1)
AND     PARSENAME(@userip, 2) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 2)
AND     PARSENAME(@userip, 3) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 3)
AND     PARSENAME(@userip, 4) LIKE PARSENAME(ip, 4);

VALIDCOUNT
----------
   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a statement where you replace the numbers of your visitor IP with '#' on each position (between the dots), and do a regular WHERE-clause. So you get a statement with a where clause containing five comparisons (one for a direct match, and four with the replacement # on each position).

You can use CHARINDEX to find the dots, and use SUBSTRING to build up the comparison varchars.

Comment: Also, I suspect the example is over simplified and that it wouldrequire more than five comparisons. Maybe... heh

Comment: Should be 15, assuming you don't have to match #.#.#.#